create a streamlit app to display a pivot table as a drill down
I am trying to create a streamlit app where i have a compliance table as below:
docid salesrep customer warehouse saledate   deliverydate compliance
doc1  abc.     cus1.    wh1.      11/1/2024. 11/10/2024.  0
doc2. abc.     cus2.    wh1.      11/4/2024. 11/20/2024.  1

Where compliance is a binary variable - 1 or 0 (100% or 0%)
I am trying to create a streamlit app which shows compliance at a warehouse level as a percentage where the user can drill down at each sales rep or customer level to see the compliance percentage at the drill down level
I can show a separate pivot table at wh level or sales rep level or customer level, i am looking to have a single table which can be drilled down on any of these dimensions.

I would suggest something like this:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = {
    'docid': ['doc1', 'doc2', 'doc3', 'doc4'],
    'salesrep': ['abc', 'abc', 'xyz', 'xyz'],
    'customer': ['cus1', 'cus2', 'cus3', 'cus4'],
    'warehouse': ['wh1', 'wh1', 'wh2', 'wh2'],
    'saledate': ['11/1/2024', '11/4/2024', '11/5/2024', '11/7/2024'],
    'deliverydate': ['11/10/2024', '11/20/2024', '11/12/2024', '11/18/2024'],
    'compliance': [0, 1, 1, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def compute_compliance_counts(df, group_by):
    grouped = df.groupby(group_by).agg(
        total_docs=('compliance', 'count'),
        compliant_docs=('compliance', 'sum')
    ).reset_index()
    grouped['compliance_percentage'] = (grouped['compliant_docs'] / grouped['total_docs'] * 100).round(2)
    return grouped

customer_compliance = compute_compliance_counts(df, ['warehouse', 'salesrep', 'customer'])

fig = px.sunburst(
    data_frame=customer_compliance,
    path=['warehouse', 'salesrep', 'customer'],
    values='total_docs',  
    color='compliance_percentage',
    color_continuous_scale='Viridis', 
    hover_data={'compliance_percentage': True},
    title="Compliance Drill-Down"
)

fig.update_traces(textinfo='label+percent entry')

fig.show()

which returns

When drilling down

